# How to Calculate $\int_{S} xyz~d{\sigma}$ where $S$ is the portion $x+y+z=1$ in the first octant $ 0 \leq x , 0 \leq y , 0 \leq z$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

> Calculate $\int_{S} xyz~d{\sigma}$  where $S$ :
>
> is the portion $x+y+z=1$ in the first octant $ 0 \leq x , 0 \leq y , 0 \leq z$ .

should i calculate

$\sqrt{3}\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x} (xy-x^2y-xy^2) dy~dx$ =

= $\sqrt{3}~\int_0^1\int_0^1 (u-1)(u-v)(v)~du~dv$

where :$ ~~~~~u = x+y ~,~~~~ v=x  ~~~, ~~~Jacobian = -1$

and so the full answer is $\boxed{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{12}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrated region in the $xy$ plane is $\{(x,y):x,y\ge0,x+y\le1\}$. $$0\le x\le1\implies0\le v\le1\\0\le y\le1\implies0\le u-v\le1\\0\le x+y\le1\implies0\le u\le1$$[image: Figure]The integrated region in $uv$ plane is the intersection of the solution regions of the above three inequalities in $u,v$;$$\{(u,v):0\le v\le u\le 1,v\le1\}$$which is not very different from the original integral. Also note that when applying change of coordinates, you are supposed to multiply by the absolute value of the jacobian. The integral should look like$$\sqrt{3}\int_0^1\int_v^1v(1-u)(u-v)~du~dv$$which gives the answer as $\dfrac{\sqrt3}{120}$.

---

**Remark.** You could just as well avoid the change of coordinates and solve it directly.$$\sqrt3\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x} xy(1-x-y)dy~dx=\sqrt3\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}x(1-x)y-xy^2dy~dx\\=\sqrt3\int_0^1\frac{x(1-x)^3}6dx=\sqrt3\int_0^1\frac{x^3(1-x)}6dx=\frac{\sqrt3}{120}$$

Comment: i didn't understand why $0\le y\le1\implies0\le u-v\le1$

Comment: It is because $y$ _is_ $(x+y)-x=u-v$

Comment: but $ 0 \leq y \leq (1-x) $  not $ 0 \leq y \leq 1$

Comment: Yes, that is covered in the third statement. $x+y\le1\implies u\le1$

Comment: if $y=1$ and $x=1$ then $z < 0$ and they want $0 \leq z $

Comment: i dont know why there are 3 statements and not 2

Comment: We have to take the intersection of the solution regions of the inequalities. I have used all available knowledge about $x,y$; you know that $0\le x,y\le1,0\le x+y\le1$. Now examine all these inequalities one by one to arrive at the bounds on $u,v$

Comment: If $y=1$, then $x=0$ since $x+y\le1$

Comment: @Mather added some visual aid, if that's of any help

Comment: the double integral before moving to $u,v$ hints that there are 2 statments : $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $0\leq y \le (1-x)$ so i used them only thats why i dont understand the new statment

Comment: we wrote $\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}$  and not  $\int_0^1\int_0^1$

Comment: @Mather Sure, that works too.$$0\le x\le1\implies0\le v\le1\\0\le y\le1-x\implies0\le u-v\le1-v$$Note that when I say $0\le y\le1$, it is not a tight bound. I obtained the integrated region in the $uv$ plane by taking the intersection of solution regions of inequalities that were not tight bounds. You are making use of tighter bounds on $y$, which means you are working with fewer inequalities, which is quicker.

Comment: In my solution, the region $1-v\le u-v\le1$ that came as a consequence of $1-x\le y\le1$ got rejected as the former doesn't lie in the solution region of $0\le u\le1$ and hence the intersection of the solution regions